# How to check if NAS is mounted and responding?

Tags: aix, storage, nas

What is the command or script to check following for a NAS:

1. It is mounted? (I used the `mount` command, but I'm not sure how to interpret its output)
2. If it is mounted, then is it responsive?

It is an AIX server.

Recently there was an network outage due to which all servers and NAS were not reachable. Once the network was restored, though NAS was automounted by some automount utility, but it was not catering to request and respond to it.

Comment: Can you include, the `mount` command you used, the output from the `df` command and the `mount` command (on it's own).  Also, to be most useful, can you include the version of AIX you're running.  Please edit your question and add that detail to it, don't add them as a comment.  Also, to confirm, you want to mount a remote filesystem and then check it worked, or you want to run a command at any time to see if your remote filesystem is mounted?  Can you clarity.

Comment: You can use the mountpoint command to check whether a given directory is a mounted filesystem

Comment: @RamanSailopal `mountpoint` appears to be a Linux command, while Somesh appears to be working with AIX (which does not have that command natively).

Comment: Somesh, what is the confusing part of the `mount` output? Was the NAS server not listed when you expected it to be? Also, what do you mean by "responsive"? That it's readable? Writable? Or some speed/performance metric?

Comment: Sadly there's little point re-opening this question until you can show us the information you've already been asked to provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NFS then it should possible to use rpcinfo to do what you describe (as I understand your question).

NFS is an RPC (ONC RPC) based protocol and systems where it is implemented should include tools such as rpcinfo.

It will allow you to make remote procedure calls to remote systems on your network, such as your NAS, and get a list of the services running/available there. It can also make calls to specific services (e.g. NFS) in order to perform a type of "application level ping" (technically it makes a call to procedure 0 of the server program which is a no-op).

Try "man rpcinfo" to get more details of the command and its options.

Comment: Another useful NFS tool in this situation would be showmount. It can show the filesystems (NFS) exported by a host for example. Rpcinfo probably better addresses the responsiveness issue.